# IP-to-IP Redirect

Tags: ip, redirection

How can i redirect an IP to another IP, cause currently i have a program connecting to old IP address, sadly its hardcoded into it and its impossible to change it without violating its EULA, i want to redirect the program to the new host, so how can i do that?

For example: the program wants to connect to X.X.X.X and i redirect it to Z.Z.Z.Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a low cost router and configure it to NAT (network address translation) the old address to the new address.

See diagram

```
<192.168.1.1>-----------<router>-----------<New PC 192.168.2.1>
```

See the port forwarding / triggering setup .

Alternatively, the IP address is probably in the registry somewhere and I bet you could update it and not break the app.