# IP to IP redirection on Windows

Tags: windows, proxy, ip, redirection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IP-to-IP Redirect](https://superuser.com/questions/188678/ip-to-ip-redirect)

I need a simple way to redirect an IP to another IP.

If in `HOSTS` I could write

```
192.168.1.2  192.168.2.3
```

that would be great.

Comment: exact concept of http://superuser.com/questions/188678/ip-to-ip-redirect

Comment: "a low cost router" is not a solution at all

Comment: maybe some windows alternative to iptables

Comment: @lublushokolad - whether the answer is what you are looking for or not, it is not appropriate to ask a duplicate question. You can offer a bounty on the existing question to obtain better answers.

Comment: i found a solution. what should id do? answer here? and there?

Comment: will somebody merge this questions?

Comment: You can flag your own question for moderator attention, and propose it to be merged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used [3proxy](http://www.3proxy.ru/?l=EN).

My `config.txt`

```
auth iponly

allow * * 83.221.199.178 80
parent 1000 tcp 192.168.1.5 8080
# redirect requests for 83.221.199.178:80 to 192.168.1.5:8080

allow *
proxy
# transparent for other requests

# default proxy port is 3128
# you can change it adding 
#proxy -p8000
```

I installed 3proxy as a service with `3proxy.exe --install config.txt`.

Comment: the zip file gets blocked by chrome as malicious